# What directories should be persisted to recreate a live-node(pod) back from a failed one in an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster running in a K8s environment?

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-artemis

If I deliberately kill a live-node(pod) that is part of a Kubernetes StatefulSet, it will be recreated automatically. Once restarted, what all should be stored on a persistent volume, so that once the pod is back up, it properly joins back the artemis cluster as the same live-node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the folders and files in the `data` directory need to be stored on a persistent volume.